# How to uncheck "Use IIS Express" when its Blurred?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Im using **Visual Studio 2012**
I want to print the name of project in link as "**localhost/PractiseMVC1**"
But after running the project its giving me the **port number** as "localhost:61698/PractiseMVC1"

I dont' want the **61698**

I have searched a lot about this and found that unchecking the "**Use IIS Express**" will do the job but nothing is working...

I have already tried unchecking **edit and continue in Tools->Option**

Please help...

[This is the screenshot of my visual studio 2012 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOwhK.png)

Comment: Why do you care about the port number in your local test environment?

Comment: im working on a project and the same thing is happening over there also sir....
My teacher wants me to remove the port number and the project name should be there with the localhost ....
:(

Comment: Do you have regular IIS installed on your computer?

Comment: Then tell your teacher he/she doesn't know what they are talking about. This is a perfectly normal way to develop software on a local machine and the port number only matters when you deploy it to a proper server where you almost certainly won't have a port number.

Comment: ok sir...
Thank You :)